# Running programs as root with my own password in Scientific Linux/Red Hat/Fedora/CentOS

Tags: fedora, gnome, rhel, sudo, scientific-linux

In Debian-derived Linux distros, if you are not `root` but are authorized in `/etc/sudoers`, GNOME will ask you for your own password to allow privileged operations.

However, Scientific Linux asks you for the real `root` password, even if you can do the same action with `sudo`. [A Google search suggests this is true for all Red Hat or Fedora-derived distros,](https://www.google.com/search?q=using%20sudo%20in%20gnome%20on%20fedora) but the suggested solutions are all very old, complex, or not very complete.

How should I configure GNOME, `gksu`, kernel PAM, polkit/PolicyKit, or what-have-you to let me use `sudo` properly within the GNOME GUI?

Answer (score 2):

Install and use `gksudo` instead, that's like a front-end of `sudo`.

gksu itself won't regard sudoers file.

Comment: There's no `gksudo` packaged for Fedora/RHEL/Centos/etc.  This is just going to lead the OP into building/installing from source, something I'd advise against for security software.

Answer (score 0):

always use visudo to edit /etc/sudoers.
You must also specify what commands you want your privileged to be able to run

user All = (ALL) ALL

You should be prompted for your own password

Comment: This is correct information but does not actually answer the question that's being asked.